# Iterate list within role task, provide each element as vars to include_tasks

Tags: loops, ansible, task, roles

Fairly new to Ansible, so I might just have the wrong approach or idea here.

I've specified role `common`, within that role's `main.yaml`, a task to iterate a list and include a task file, while providing variables based on each list element.

In my playbook, at the end I define:

```yaml
roles:
   - role: common
    tags: [ never, common ]
```

And the task within `roles/common/tasks/main.yaml`

```yaml
- name: Create user accounts
  include_tasks: tasks/create_user.yaml
  vars:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    grps: "{{ item.groups }}"
  with_items:
    - { name: user1, groups: group1 }
    - { name: user2, groups: group2 }
  tags: [ never, users ]
```

And within the `tasks/create_user.yaml`, for testing if iteration and variables works:

```yaml
---
- name: Print user and groups
  debug:
    msg: "{{ user }} and {{ grps }}"
```

Running the playbook, against host `test-host`, I get:

```
TASK [common : Create user accounts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /...path.../tasks/create_user.yaml for test-host
included: /...path.../tasks/create_user.yaml for test-host
```

without any tasks executed.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Grateful for any input.

Comment: Which command did you use to launch your playbook and more specifically which tag(s) did you pass? For your debug to run, you need to use the `never` or `users` tag on the command line.

Comment: ``include_tasks`` don't inherit the tags. Change it to ``import_tasks`` and it will be fine. The difference is that ``import_tasks`` imports the code before execution. On the contrary in ``include_tasks`` Ansible will learn what's inside when the execution reaches the include statement. Imagine, for example, *ansible-playbook* option ``--list-tags`` can't show what's inside included tasks and roles. See [What's the difference between include_tasks and import_tasks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/875247/whats-the-difference-between-include-tasks-and-import-tasks). Is it a duplicate?

Comment: Zeitounator I launched it as "ansible-playbook -i test-host, playbook/common-test.yaml --tags users" yesterday.

I recreated this today at my home lab, and got it working ootb. Realised I used
tag "common" instead of "users", tried tag "users" and it broke again. Based on @VladimirBotka mentioning of no inheritance for include_tasks, I added tags "users" to file "tasks/create_user.yaml", and it started working using tag "users". So it was
 on point! Thanks for getting back about this!

Comment: The usage of ``include_tasks`` is justified if the [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#parameter-file) is dynamic. Otherwise, ``import_tasks`` should be used.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Sorry forgot to mention it, when I try to use import_tasks I get this error:

ERROR! You cannot use loops on 'import_tasks' statements. You should use 'include_tasks' instead.

Comment: Right. You can put the list of users into vars and iterate it inside imported tasks. The next option is *apply* tags. It's a rather complex decision. I've tried and put together some aspects in the answer below. In the end, it is your case and you know all the details. You choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the options below and the final note in particular. For testing, the tasks below

```yaml
    - include_tasks: test-debug.yml
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      vars:
        users: [alice, bob, charlie]
      tags: t1

    - debug:
        msg: End of play.
      tags: t1
```

```yaml
shell> cat test-debug.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
```

will execute the **included** debug without tags specified

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml | grep msg
...
  msg: alice
  msg: bob
  msg: charlie
  msg: End of play.
```

The **included** debug won't be executed when the tag *t1* is specified because included tasks do not inherit tags

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t t1 | grep msg
...
  msg: End of play.
```

There are more options on how to solve the problem. Put the tags into the included tasks, import the tasks, or apply the tags to the included tasks

**1) Put tags in the included tasks**

```yaml
shell> cat test-debug.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  tags: t1
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t t1 | grep msg
  msg: alice
  msg: bob
  msg: charlie
  msg: End of play.
```

**2) Import tasks**

*import_tasks* [cannot be used in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#comparing-includes-and-imports-dynamic-and-static-re-use). It's possible to put the list into the *vars* and iterate it inside imported tasks

```yaml
    - import_tasks: test-debug.yml
      vars:
        users: [alice, bob, charlie]
      tags: t1
```

```yaml
shell> cat test-debug.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t t1 | grep msg
  msg: alice
  msg: bob
  msg: charlie
  msg: End of play.
```

**3) Apply tags**

The next option is to [apply](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance-for-includes-blocks-and-the-apply-keyword) the tags

```yaml
    - include_tasks:
        file: test-debug.yml
        apply:
          tags: t1
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      vars:
        users: [alice, bob, charlie]
      tags: t1

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: End of play.
      tags: t1
```

```yaml
shell> cat test-debug.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t t1 | grep msg
  msg: alice
  msg: bob
  msg: charlie
  msg: End of play.
```

---

The decision between *include_tasks* and *import_tasks* is a trade-off. The main advantage of included tasks is the possibility to iterate more tasks. The disadvantage is (quoting from [Comparing includes and imports: dynamic and static re-use](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#comparing-includes-and-imports-dynamic-and-static-re-use)):

> Note: There are also big differences in resource consumption and performance, imports are quite lean and fast, while includes require a lot of management and accounting.

Comment: Aright, thanks for the write down and clarifying, I'm learning a lot, and that there's plenty more to learn with Ansible!